# Handling query string with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, controller, helper

A complete rails beginner here.
How do I go about handling a query string in rails?
For example for:
www.something.com/movie?sort=title

For implementing the the view in the haml file, how can I make it so that clicking on Movie title will send that query string,
And more importantly how do I handle it. Where should I implement the function which can access that query string using :params .

I have been on this for more than a day now and could not understand whether that query string will call a controller function or a module from helper.

I hope I was clear enough about the question.
Any help will be appreciated.

PS:- there is a movie table with title as one of its column.

Comment: Do you have a controller named 'movies' and a model named movie.rb in your application.If so I can write some code. If you don't know what is controller and model please visit http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Comment: yes, controller and model is present....
However, it is part of a HW assignment so I would prefer to write the code myself...thanks for the link however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I really understand what you want. Does this suit you?

```
link_to "My Link", movie_index_path(sort: :title)
```

Then access param with `params[:sort]` ?

(Accord `movie_index_path` with your routes configuration)

Comment: and it would be mighty helpful if you could point me to somewhere where I can learn more(read:everything from beginning) about routes configuration.

Comment: Didn't understood your first comment though.

Comment: the "My Link" in your  example is the value of a table header. so, when i tried <code> %th link_to "Movie Title", Movie_index_path( sort :title) </code> ,it actually shows the whole "link_to "Movie Title", Movie_index_path( sort :title)" as the value for that table heading.

Comment: %th .. you are using HAML? so it would be `%th= link_to...`

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is not focused let me assume part of your problem.

Assumptions

1. You have a controller name movies_controller.rb in app/controllers/
2. folder You have a model named movie.rb in app/models folder

Then you should tell Rails to route requests with path /movies to movies_controller.rb. This can be done by adding the below lines in config/routes.rb

```
resources :movies
```

The if you call www.something.com/movies this will invoke the method index in movies_controller.rb. So you should write some code to display movies here.

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
 def index
   @movies = Movie.all
 end
end
```

Then you should use app/views/movies/index.haml file to display the movies. There give a link to sort the movies by title.

```
link_to "Sort by title", movies_path(:sort=>"title")
```

No when click on the link the user will reach the same index method with params now. You can get the sort value like below.

```
params[:sort]
```

SO to support sorting you need to change the controller code little bit.

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
 def index
  if params[:sort]
   @movies = Movie.order('#{params[:sort]} ASC')
  else
    @movies = Movie.all
  end
 end 
end
```

I strongly suggest you to go through the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html before asking question.